# Flutter: just_audio playing on multiple pages

Tags: flutter

I created a "page", which is an audio player with just_audio and it's working perfectly.

However, when I click back, it stops playing the audio and I would like it to continue playing the configured playlist.

Only if I select a new playlist should it stop the current audio and move on to the newly selected audio.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I'm also using just_audio_backgroun and the audio plays perfectly with the screen locked.

But I want you to keep touching other pages in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the just_audio settings in just one view so when you open another view the audio stops. If you want to keep the audio being played you need to move your audio to a higher level or to a notifier, so separating your UI from your logic would help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is that, you have to use one instance of AudioPlayer and then that instance use it across all of your screens.

My solution i use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for statemanagement in my app so it was pretty straight forward here is my code for the `appstatestore.dart` file

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
class AppStateStore with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
}
```

Then i register it on my `main.dart` file

```dart
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

Future main() async {
runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppStateStore()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then i used it on my `audio_play.dart` file or basically any file that you want to access it.

```dart
Provider.of<AppStateStore>(context, listen: false)
              .audioPlayer
// or if you want to listen for notifiers
Provider.of<AppStateStore>(context)
              .audioPlayer
// also you could this
context.watch<AppStateStore>().audioPlayer
```

I hope it helps. here is the link for [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package.